# Tossing a coin $n$ times, probability for a palindrome?

Tags: probability, palindrome

> Tossing a coin $n$ times, calculate the probability for a palindrome result?

So I said

> We have $2 \choose 1$ options for throws $1,n$, $2 \choose 1$ options for throws $2, n-1$.... thus: $P(A) = \frac{ \frac{n}{2} \cdot {2 \choose 1} }{2^n}$

Is that correct?

Comment: For the case $n=3$ i count 4 palidromes out of 8 combinations. your formula gives 3 out of 8, so it can't be right. I don't really follow your argument though. Maybe it'd be easier if you considered cases where $n$ was even and odd separately.

Comment: Maybe upper (edited) bound of $\frac{n}{2}$?

Answer (score 4):

if n is even the probability is $(\frac{1}{2})^{n/2}$.

if n is odd the probability is $(\frac{1}{2})^{(n-1)/2}$.

I think the above is the correct answer as each flip in the first half sets up a requirement for the second half.  I don't think there is anything I am missing to make the problem more complicated.

Comment: Interesting way to look at it!
Can anyone confirm?